# g++ Cygwin/Linux or version discrepancy

Tags: c++, linux, linker, cygwin, shared-libraries

Can someone explain the discrepancy in how two instances of g++ handle compilation of the following code to shared libraries?

`Foo.h`

```
#ifndef Foo_h
#define Foo_h

void Foo();

#endif // Foo_h
```

`Foo.cpp`

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void Foo()
{
    std::cout << "Greetings from Foo()!" << std::endl;
}
```

`Bar.h`

```
#ifndef Bar_h
#define Bar_h

void Bar();

#endif // Bar_h
```

`Bar.cpp`

```
#include "Bar.h"
#include "Foo.h"
#include <iostream>

void Bar()
{
    Foo();
    std::cout << "Greetings from Bar()!" << std::endl;
}
```

On a true Linux box:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

>g++ -fpic -c Foo.cpp
>g++ -fpic -c Bar.cpp
>g++ -shared -o libFoo.so Foo.o
>g++ -shared -o libBar.so Bar.o
>
```

On Cygwin:

```
>g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 5.4.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>g++ -fpic -c Foo.cpp
>g++ -fpic -c Bar.cpp
>g++ -shared -o libFoo.so Foo.o
>g++ -shared -o libBar.so Bar.o
Bar.o:Bar.cpp:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `Foo()'
Bar.o:Bar.cpp:(.text+0x9): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Foo()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't really have enough *nix-savvy to know how to install different/matching versions of g++ on either box to see if that is the cause of the problem (on one of the boxes I wouldn't have the privilege to do so, anyway).

I'd always thought that object files, and by extension, libraries - either static or shared - were allowed to have unresolved symbols, and that it's only when linking an executable that all symbols needed to be resolved. That concept has pretty much held true over several years of development experience, too, so I'm baffled by the error generated on Cygwin. I'm very curious to know what's happening here. Thank you.

**UPDATE**

An answerer below provided the following suggestion which works: `g++ -shared -o libBar.so Bar.o libFoo.so`

Look at the resulting contents of libBar.so:

```
>nm --demangle libBar.so | grep Foo
00000004e4b791c4 I __imp__Z3Foov
00000004e4b7903c I _head_libFoo_so
00000004e4b71750 T Foo()
00000004e4b793ec I libFoo_so_iname
```

Per my understanding, this means that `Foo()` is binary-included in libBar.so, i.e. the compiled binary content of `Foo()` is present in libBar.so.

This is a bit different than the picture I'd had in my head based on the behavior on the true Linux box. I thought each `.so` would be "standalone" binary code, just like a `.o` file, or a `.a` file that was comprised of only one object file.

I guess what I'm having trouble wrapping my head around is that the Cygwin (or g++ 5.4) behavior is saying that a *library* cannot have unresolved symbols - this feels contrary to what a lot of prior experience has ingrained in me. I get that an executable cannot have unresolveds, but a library ought to be able to have unresolveds, right? After all, you can't *execute* a library - it has no `main()`. I know for sure that *static* libraries can have unresolveds, and I thought difference between shared and static libraries is whether their code is link-time *added* to the executable binary, or whether their code is runtime looked-up by the executable.

Appreciate further clarity the community can shed here. Thank you.

Comment: On Windows there  are no shared objects. There are DLLs. Cugwin tries its best to hide the difference but it can only do so much. A DLL is not allowed to have unresolved symbols by default.

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is (or seems to me) contradictory to @MartinBonner 's. I'm going to try understand this all a little deeper. In the meanwhile, if you're pretty certain of your postion, could you post it as an answer along with any further explanation/background that you think is relevant?

Comment: It most certainly is. See https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-06/msg00448.html

Comment: @n.m. - Ah! That explains it! You should post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no shared objects on Windows. There are DLLs. DLLs behave differently from Un*x shared objects. In particular, *they are not allowed to have undefined symbols*. The PE (Portable Executable) format used in Windows for both DLLs and executables just doesn't have a way to express them. Google "pe dll" "undefined symbols", there's a lot of info around.

Cygwin tries very hard to hide peculiarities of Windows from the programmer but there's only so much it can do.

When you link `libBar.so` against `libFoo.so`, code from `libFoo.so` is **not** physically included in `libBar.do`. That would defeat the purpose of DLLs to be loaded at run time. Instead, the linking process creates *stubs* for all functions imported from other DLLs. These are not real functions. You can make sure this is indeed the case by looking for strings:

```
% strings libFoo.so | grep "Greetings from"
Greetings from Foo
% strings libBar.so | grep "Greetings from"
Greetings from Bar
```

Comment: Thank you and @MartinBonner as well; Consolidating both your answers, I think I understand now a bit more about how Cygwin tries to abstract away Windows specifics - but I guess those specifics are made evident at this level of inspection. I think, then, if I repeated my experiment with g++ 5.4 on a true *nix box, I would observe expected behavior, i.e. that shared libs don't need to be linked against each other _and_ can have unresolved symbols. The "defined" symbols I see when I run `nm` must be the stubs you spoke of. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more g++ 5.4 vs 4.4 (that's a big difference by the way) than cygwin vs Linux.

A shared object is a very different beast to an object file.  In some ways it is more like an executable.  The model that 5.4 is using, is that when it links the shared object, it doesn't need to have copies of all the symbols in its hand, but *it needs to tell the run-time loader which shared objects the loader can find the remaining symbols in*.  I suggest:

```
g++ -shared -o libBar.so Bar.o libFoo.so
```

(Alternatively, you can use `-lFoo` if you like, but then you'll need to set up the library paths correctly).

The more interesting question is why g++ 4.4 works as is: That I don't know.

### Why does `nm` show `Foo` in `libBar.so`?

`Foo()` is *not* binary included in `libBar.so`.  The following is very handy-wavy and approximate.  If you want more accuracy, you are going to have to read about the loader and the format of executable files.

The assembler of `libBar.so` is going to look something like:

```
Bar():
    CALL 000000    # The zeros are a blank that will be filled in by
                   # the loader with the address of Foo
    PUSH "Greetings from Bar()!"
    PUSH 000000    # Blank to be filled with address of std::cout
    CALL 000000    # Blank to be filled with address of
                   # std::ostream::operator<<(const char*)
... etc
```

Then elsewhere in `libBar.so` there will be a section that says something like:

```
Bar+1    Foo
Bar+9    std::cout
Bar+11   std::ostream::operator<<(const char *)
```

which tells the loader to fill in `Bar+1` with the address for `Foo`.  Finally there will be a section that says:

```
Foo                                   libFoo.so
std::cout                             libc.so
std::ostream::operator<<(const char*) libc.so
```

which tells the loader that it can find `Foo` in `libFoo.so` etc.  It is that last section which `nm` is reporting.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinBonner. I'm going to modify my question based on your answer, because it dovetails into a related issue. I guess the community can let me know if it is better done as a separate question.

Comment: If your modification changes things so much that the answer is different, then it *probably* means it's better as a separate question.  If you are just supplying more info about this question, go ahead.